# Retrieving original JSON code from a decoded array node in Perl

Tags: json, perl, utf-8

I'm working on a script which receives JSON code for an array of objects similar to this:

```
{
  "array":[
    { "id": 1, "text": "Some text" },
    { "id": 2, "text": "Some text" }
  ]
}
```

I decode it using JSON::XS and then filter out some of the results.  After this, I need to store the JSON code **for each individual node** into a queue for later processing.  The format this queue requires is JSON too, so the code I'd need to insert for each node would be something like this:

```
{ "id": 1, "text": "Some text" }
```

However, after **decode_json** has decoded a node, all that's left are hash references for each node:

```
print $json->{'array'}[0]; # Would print something like HASH(0x7ffa80c83270)
```

I know I could get something similar to the original JSON code using **encode_json** on the hash reference, but the resulting code is different from the original code, UTF-8 characters get all weird, and it seems like a lot of extra processing, specially considering the amount of data this script has to deal with.

Is there a way to retrieve the original JSON code from a decoded array node?  Does JSON::XS keep the original chunks somewhere after they have been decoded?

---

**EDIT**

About the weird UTF-8 characters, they just look weird on the screen:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use JSON::XS;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

$old_json = '{ "text": "Drag\u00f3n" }';
$json = decode_json($old_json);
print $json->{'text'}; # Dragón

$new_json = encode_json($json);
print $new_json; # {"text":"DragÃ³n"}

$json = decode_json($new_json);
print $json->{'text'}; # Dragón
```

Comment: Re your edit: Yes, when you encode something using UTF-8 twice, it's going to look weird on a UTF-8 terminal. don't do that.

Comment: Remember what `decode_json` and `encode_json` is short for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`encode_json` will produce equivalent JSON to what you originally had before you decoded it with `decode_json`. Characters encoded using UTF-8 do not get all weird.

```
$ cat a.pl
use Encode   qw( encode_utf8 );
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json encode_json );

my $json = encode_utf8(qq!{"name":"\x{C9}ric" }!);
print($json, "\n");
print(encode_json(decode_json($json)), "\n");

$ perl a.pl | od -c
0000000   {   "   n   a   m   e   "   :   " 303 211   r   i   c   "    
0000020   }  \n   {   "   n   a   m   e   "   :   " 303 211   r   i   c
0000040   "   }  \n
0000043
```

If you want a parser that preserves the original JSON, you'll surely have to write your own; the existing ones don't do that.

Comment: If by weird you mean it replaces the UTF-8 encoding (5C 75 32 36 36 30) of the 6 chars `\u2660` with the UTF-8 encoding (E2 99 A0) of the character that represents (♠), you're mistaken. That's perfectly fine.

Comment: So... now the JSON code goes into the MySQL queue, I extract it, and when I try to decode it i get this error: **malformed UTF-8 character in JSON string**... any ideas?

Comment: yeah, comments aren't the place to ask new questions. Be sure to be precise about your data (`use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper(...));`)

Comment: Sorry about that... just getting to know the rules.  I solved it by encoding to UTF-8 before decoding JSON `$json = decode_json(encode_utf8($text));`

Comment: Pretty sure you have a two-wrongs-make-a-right situation. You are decoding-encoding-decoding instead of just decoding.

Comment: I have to decode so I can filter out some of the results, then I have to encode in order to put it into a processing queue which is filled by several different scripts, and then, the script that reads the queue and processes the information has to decode it again.  I know this sucks, but I haven't found a better alternative.

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't decode, I said you should decode-encode-decode. Before you do the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't exist anywhere. The "original JSON" isn't stored per-element; it's decoded in a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Every JSON object can have multiple, but equivalent representations:

```
{ "key": "abc" }
```

and

```
{
  "key" : "abc" 
}
```

are pretty much the same.

So just use the re-encoded JSON your module gives you.

1. Even if JSON::XS caches the chunks, extracting them would be a breach of encapsulation, therefore having no guarantee of working if the module is upgraded. And it is bad design.
2. Don't care about performance. The `XS` modules have exceptional performance, as they are coded in C. And if you were paranoid about performance, you wouldn't use JSON but some binary format. And you wouldn't be using Perl, but Fortran ;-)
3. You should treat equivalent data as equivalent data. Even if the presentation is different.
4. If the unicode chars look weird, but process fine, there is no problem. If they don't get processed correctly, you might have to specify an exact encoding.

Comment: Re-encoding what was previously decoded feels like a performance issue... but, unless I write my own parser, it seems like I will have to let that go.  Thank you very much.